# Netbeans not working correctly on debian

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, debian, netbeans-8

Have been woking with netbeans on windows for ages and no problem.
Installed it on Debian and it starts but most buttons doesn't respond (new project/new file ...).

Here's the resut while launching it with terminal.

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/home/mssm1996/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Details:

Netbeans version: 8.2
OS: Parrot (distribution of debian OS)
JDK version: 9.0.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem.
Installed jdk 8 and configured netbeans so that its java_home becames (jdk 8) in the file /etc/netbeans.conf

Comment: I have the same problem, can you expose the solution with more datails?

Comment: I've removed java 9, and installed java 8 since the last version of netbeans supports only the version 8 of jdk, and configure netbeans (the path to the jdk 8 folder)

Comment: Add this line in your `/etc/netbeans.conf` file : ` netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/" `

Comment: netbeans_jdkhome="c:\develop\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_191"